# How to Check if a String is a Palindrome

Tags: python-3.x

My codes are below. I am inexperienced coder, I think the problem is with the `.join(reversed())` part. However, I can't figure out why. I need someone else to check this again, maybe I missed out something.

```py
def is_palindrome(alist):
    truth = []
    for i in alist:
        i.lower()
        i.replace(" ","")
        x = "".join(reversed(i))
        if i == x:
            truth.append(True)
        else:
            truth.append(False)
    return truth
test_list = ['Stats', 'A nut for a jar of Tuna', 'I eat apples']
print(is_palindrome(test_list))
print(test_list)
```

The results given is:

```
[False, False, False]
```

It is supposed to be:

```
[True,True,False]
```

Anyone have any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: The title of your question is somewhat obtuse.  Something like, "How to Check if a String is a Palindrome" would be more to the point.

Comment: The previous title was "where have I went wrong with reversed()"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lower()` and `replace()` functions are not in-place.

You must assign their return value to `i`.

```
i=i.lower()
i=i.replace(" ","")
```

Output:

```
[True, True, False]                                
['Stats', 'A nut for a jar of Tuna', 'I eat apples']
```

Answer (score 6):

Both `.lower()` and `.replace(...)` are not in place

```py
def is_palindrome(alist):
    truth = []
    for i in alist:
        i=i.lower()
        i=i.replace(" ","")
        x = "".join(reversed(i))
        truth.append(i == x)
    return truth
test_list = ['Stats', 'A nut for a jar of Tuna', 'I eat apples']
print(is_palindrome(test_list))
print(test_list)
```

Comment: `truth.append(i == x)`